# Incompatible return type when overriding methods of Generic classes in Java

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I was playing around with generics, and I found a problem I really can't figure out.
Please take a look at this code:

```
class Operation<R> {
}

class P<O extends Operation<R>, R> {
}

class MyResource {
}

class MyO extends Operation<MyResource> {
}

class MyP extends P<MyO, MyResource> {
}

abstract class A<R> {
    abstract P<Operation<R>, R> doIt();
}

class B extends A<MyResource> {
    @Override
    MyP doIt() {
    /*
        the compiler is complaining about the above line:
        The return type is incompatible with A<MyResource>.doIt()
    */
        return null;
    }
}
```

So basically, `MyP` is a subclass of `P<MyO, MyResource>` which in turn is a subclass of
`P<Operation<MyResource>, MyResource>`. In other words, we are returning a subclass of `A.doIt` return type in `B.doIt`. But nevertheless, the compiler is complaining.

Can you help me to understand this ? 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Overriding return type of extended interface when return type uses generics for own method parameter types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056595/java-overriding-return-type-of-extended-interface-when-return-type-uses-generi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `MyP` is a `P<MyO,>`, which is not the same as a `P<Operation<MyResource>,>` (even though it does inherit it).
You need to change the abstract method's return type to be covariant in that parameter:

```
abstract class A<R> {
    abstract P<? extends Operation<R>, R> doIt();
}
```

Now, `MyP` is convertible to the base return type, so everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your claim that `P<MyO, MyResource>` is a subclass of `P<Operation<MyResource>, MyResource>` is incorrect. These kinds of relations do not hold in Java, and the reason is that the generic class could use its type parameter in either covariant or contravariant fashion (or both).  If the usage is anything but strictly covariant, the automatic subtype relationship you propose would be unsound.  @SLaks has the right idea.

Comment: Indeed that was the issue in my reasoning. Thanks.